# WPF Datagrid manual update object value only after cell edit finished

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell

I am using a WPF datagrid that has a column that binds to a decimal field which also displays a £ sign to show as a currency. I then catch the CellEditEnding events to compare old results and create audits etc. This works well and does not update any values until the cell edit has ended due to the £ causing a conflict. However, if the £ sign is removed from the cell and a valid decimal results in the cell, the value seems to be updated on the bound object before the cell is tabbed from and my code to deal with the change is not fired.

Comment: So what is your question ? :)

Comment: A converter would make this much simpler

Comment: i guess decimal cells won't accept special characters you're entering in the field ..
You better give a code sample or a screenshot of your application for better understandability